# Check Or Find If Value Exists In Another Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

It should be very easy but I just can not understand whats wrong anymore.
I have 3 columns, first and third column has numbers and I want the second column to show if a number in column 1 exists in column 3.
I have found a code online

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A7;$C$2:$C$3400; 1; FALSE));"Not Exist";"Exist" )
```

Now I know the number "5568" exist in A7 and the same number "5568" exists in C2365.

But the code above gives me value "Not Exist".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

**Sheet Structure:**

[image]

**Formula:**

`=IF(COUNTIF($C$1:$C$5,A1)>0,"Exist","Not Exists")`

**Note:**

- Check for spaces before or after the values using `Trim`
- You could also use `Clean`

Comment: @user245255 Then consider marking that answer as correct. Based on the note of @Error 1004, you could wrap `Trim` around your lookup-range.

Comment: We do not need to check >0 or not. Because if value is not found in a column then CountIf will return 0. So 0 in if condition is treated as false. This should be enough =IF(COUNTIF($C$1:$C$5,A1),"Exist","Not Exists")